# Using Guice annotations in Play (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, guice

Imagine a class B as follow :

```
class B @Inject() (wsClient: WSClient) {
  ...
}
```

Then in another class A, I need to instantiate B :

```
class A {
  val b = new B()
}
```

It's gonna complain saying that I haven't specified wsClient in my constructor.
One way to fix this is to modify A :

```
class A @Inject() (wsClient: WSClient) {
  val b = new B(wsClient)
}
```

I could also add an Implicit in my class B. But in both case, it just seems very wrong to me to send the dependency like this ...

How could I do it in a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of doing DI is to have [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Your bindings decide how the application is built as opposed to the classes in the application being responsible for their own control flow.

The line `val b = new B(wsClient)` is a violation of this principle as the class is responsible for knowing how it should constitute itself as opposed to the DI framework being responsible for that.

```
class B @Inject() (ws: WSClient){}

class A @Inject() (b: B) // extends B
{}
```

As @zoltan alluded to, injecting B into A would be the right way to go about solving the problem.

Comment: By doing some, how can I access ws in my class A ? b.ws doesn't work, does that mean that I need to bind it inside class B ?

Comment: If A needs ws then inject it into A

Comment: Then I have to duplicate the @Inject() (ws: WSClient) in both A and B despite injecting B into A ?

Comment: A's dependency on B should not be a transitive dependency on WS. Any operation that A does on B should be independent of the fact that B has WS injected

Answer (score 1):

Why not have `B` injected into `A`?

```
class A @Inject() (b: B)
```

if your class `B` needs to be a singleton, just annotate it with `javax.inject.Singleton`.

Comment: I see, that solves one issue.
However, the same problem happens with inheritance, if A extends B, I will have to inject in A and passes all the deps injected inside B then ?